# PayPal (Person to Person) payment android code

Tags: android, paypal, payment

I want to develop an application that I need to transfer money between 2 users using Paypal, 
I have the codes to transfer money from person to business account that provided by PayPal.
is it possible to change the code into person to person payment, or there is special codes for that?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Answer (score 0):

As Md Abdul Gafur, PayPal has a new API that let's you

> send money in many different scenarios, from simple to complex.

You can check it out [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/), where it is very nicely described what exactly happens and how to use it. You can setup very complex payments with fees and multiple receivers, but from your post I see you want a simple `person -> person` payment, which is also in the web page.
Also if you scroll down you will find samples of requests that needs to be sent to the PayPal servers in order to make a payment.